# PhpSpreadsheet Conditional formatting (Squared)

Tags: phpspreadsheet

I am new to php programming area.
I have a question, I would like to use conditional to format a column, for example if the values of Column B are different to the squared ones of each value of Column A then change the background color red if everything is right change to green.

Please I need a help

Answer (score 0):

See phpspreadsheet documentation [here](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/recipes/#conditional-formatting-a-cell).